# Linux Shell Script - Dúvida sobre escopo de variável

Tags: linux, shell-script

Num *script* shell, quero fazer um array contendo os arquivos de determinada pasta.

Tentei assim:

```
declare -a array_arquivos
i=0
ls -1 /caminho/minha_pasta | while read file; do
    array_arquivos[$i]="$file"
    ((i++))
done
```

Porém, não dá certo pois o *array* `array_arquivos` criado no início do *script* não é visível ali dentro do pipe, pois este cria um novo subshell. Com isso o `array_arquivos` não é populado. Mas, desse jeito aqui deu certo:

```
declare -a array_arquivos
i=0     
while read file; do
    array_arquivos[$i]="$file"
    ((i++))
done <<< $(ls -1 /caminho/minhapasta)
```

Ou seja, ao invés de usar pipe, mandei o resultado do LS para o meu loop através do operador `<<<`. Ou seja, problema resolvido.
Porém, ali no primeiro exemplo que não funcionou, fiquei sem entender o seguinte:
Por que a variável `array_arquivos` não é visível dentro do pipe, mas a variável `$i` é visível, sendo que as duas variáveis foram criadas juntas no começo do *script*?

Comment: Só para melhorar para a comunidade amigo. A dúvida tem que ser resumida no título da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Já entendi o que acontece. No primeiro exemplo, as duas variáveis são sim visíveis dentro do pipe. Porém, modificando as variáveis ali dentro, as modificações só valem ali. Ou seja, as mesmas variáveis, vistas fora do pipe, continuam como foram declaradas no inicio do script. Isso não é um problema para a variável $i, pois não a uso mais após terminar o loop. Mas no caso da variável array_arquivos, ela é sim populada, mas isso só terá efeito dentro do loop. Quando tento pegar a variável novamente após terminar o loop, ela continua em branco, como foi declarada no inicio do script. Espero que essa observação possa ser útil pra alguém.